# Querying ~100MB VarBinary Timeout - ASP.NET MVC / Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having a timeout issues with files of only 100MB. Is there something I can do to increase performance? I'm only handling one SQL Server entry at a time.

Extending the timeout duration is not an option based on my application's requirements.

For example: removing one entry times out on its own.

```
var entry = new TestModel { Id = id };
TestModel entity = db.ExampleTable.Attach(entry);

if (null != entity)
{
    db.ExampleTable.Remove(entity);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Data structure is nothing exceptional, just a some strings/ints and one `varbinary(MAX)` column.

How can I speed up the operation? Surely deleting one 100mb file from SQL Server should not take thing long?

Comment: While I appreciate the relational-integrity offered by keeping everything in the DB, alarm-bells ring when I see stories [like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171822/slow-delete-with-varbinarymax-column). I'd opt for the filesystem over the DB every time when it comes to large binary blobs.

Comment: This also makes an interesting read: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/211261